# Changing mailing and e-mail addresses as corresponding author--which to include?

Tags: publications, authorship, correspondence

I finished my undergrad last year and have since been working in the private sector.  I'm about to submit a paper with my senior thesis results.  Two questions about corresponding author information:

1. I'm listing my current affiliation in the private sector for various reasons.  We are moving offices, and our address will be changing in about 3 months.  **Should I use the new mailing address or the old mailing address?**  I know it's kind of silly since nobody sends mail anymore, but I'm curious either way.
2. I will probably be going to grad school in a couple of years, and my private sector e-mail will *not* be accessible if I leave.  **Would it be passé for me to list my @gmail.com address for correspondence to ensure I'm always reachable?**

Thanks!

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the most important identifier is your name. If you stay in the field, people will be able to find you by just searching your name on <search engine>. The contact info is really just there as a convenience measure.

Comment: @eykanal tell that to John Smith and Wei Chang :)

Comment: @eykanal ... and Dave Clarke.

Comment: @DaveClarke Ha! Very good point, hopefully people could just add the university name... I see that "[Dave Clarke Leuven](http://www.google.com/search?q=dave%20clarke%20Leuven)" does return your page as the first result. There's hope after all!

Comment: Unless, of course, the university changes after publication…

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. I agree with you and shan23, it doesn't really matter, but the newer is probably better.
2. Well, to be bluntly honest, I tend to have a negative a-priori when I see an author of a paper with a gmail address (especially when I review it, when it's not double-blind). I know it's stupid, because it should only be about the quality of the work, but I can't really help it. Mostly because I know that there is no authentication with gmail address (I potentially could get an alan.turing@gmail.com address). I think it's ok to give an address that will change, after all, few people spend their entire career in the same institution.

Comment: From a reviewers perspective, do you think it's any better to have the e-mail domain be a private sector company?  In my case that's the alternative--a consulting firm that is loosely involved in the field.

Comment: @Charles - well, I guess that's why we have a double blind system in most (if not all) conferences/journals, to remove this bias!

Comment: @dmahr It's hard to generalize for other reviewers, but yes, as a reviewer myself, I think it's better to have the e-mail domain of a private sector company rather than a gmail address.

Comment: @shan23 I agree, but I have to admit that I will get the same bias when I read the paper (which also a reason why I don't like double-blind, because I can't see why the reviewer shouldn't read the paper as the reader will do if accepted).

Comment: @CharlesMorisset Thanks for your opinion as a reviewer.  In your opinion, do you think the negative bias towards gmail.com authors outweighs the inconvenience of having an unreachable email address in 18 months time?

Comment: @dmahr In my personal opinion, yes it does. I'm doing my third postdoc right now, meaning that I've had 4 different affiliations over the past 5 years, and each time, I've used the email I had at the time, I don't think it ever impacted me.

Comment: @CharlesMorisset Thanks so much for the detailed explanation!

Comment: Since you mention the lack of authentication, _anyone_ can fake a university address as sender as well, and some can possibly even a backdoor to hijack a true account (although, to what avail...?). But maybe it's time to think about [PGP](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/2886/442) more, for a lot of other reasons as well

Comment: @TobiasKienzler: sure, but it's much harder to fake as receiver ... whereas I can potentially create any named address on gmail, and receive emails on it.

Comment: @CharlesMorisset That's why hope using a PGP key for your permanent email address and having it signed by your universities and colleagues will establish someday...

Answer (score 8):

1. As you mentioned, the postal address does not matter - but in any case, I'd lean towards the newer address!
2. Its definitely OK to do so - I submitted my Masters thesis with my gmail.com account, due to the exact same scenario as outlined by you (currently working, am hoping to go to grad school this fall).