# Does publishing a paper with a non-edu email influence the review process?

Tags: publications, email, affiliation

I saw many good papers on good journals (by Springer, Elsevier, IEEE, etc.) with a Gmail as a corresponding email.

I'm about to submit a paper and since I don't have (yet) an academic email, I would like to know how bad is it to publish a paper with a Gmail account. Does it have influence on the author's reputation or the reviewing process?

Comment: Related: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2872/e-mail-address-to-use-in-publications

Comment: Standard caveats apply: don't use an obnoxious or questionable username, and you will be fine

Comment: I would argue that Gmail looks much better than yahoo or hotmail in the paper.

Comment: @seteropere I don't see why, though. Probably just because it's "in" now? (Seems to be in, with the 4 comment upvotes...)

Comment: If you're genuinely concerned just get your own domain, only costs $10/year.

Comment: Note that .edu domains only concerns US institutions.

Comment: Going back 10 years, hotmail and yahoo was very limited and only used by people that could not get a "real" email account.   They were also used by spammer to create many fake email accounts.

There days, that has all changed, but memory lives for along time.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

None. Outside/commercial email addresses are more likely to be permanent than academic ones, since people change jobs all the time. I think that a Gmail or Yahoo address is fine, and I rarely look at them when reviewing. Some venues use double-blind reviewing, so the reviewers won't know your email address or affiliation anyway.

Comment: +1 This is the reason I put my Gmail address on all my papers. If I hadn't I might already be missing correspondence directed to my previous affiliation's email.

Comment: Speaking as somebody who publishes using a .com address, I absolutely concur.

Comment: @Miguel Would an affiliated institution not look down on that though? A sign that you're perhaps not intending stay, or that you're distancing yourself?

Comment: @OllieFord, I would hope that such institutions (and presumably we really only mean tenure committees, here), wouldn't be so petty or try to read such "signs". You're going to put down your institutional affiliation directly above or below your email address (or in a footnote, or whatever). I wouldn't sweat the fact that someone might look down on you for using a personal or commercial email address. If they want you to commit, they can offer you tenure.

Comment: BillBarth Hell yeah, offer me tenure and I'll be sending errata around just to get the email addresses changed. @OllieFord I've never had a complaint, usually institutions are happy to be mentioned in the normal way (usually below my name) and funding agencies in the acknowledgments.

Comment: @Martin I disagree. Some older people might even have trouble using email (or just don't read email, it happened recently to me). As someone in my late 20s I have grown up and am familiar using the internet, yet I sometimes have trouble finding a working email address for someone who has a ton of institutional webpages each with a different email. Some people are *very* hard to track on the internet.

Comment: @Martin Again I disagree, not everybody who does not want their info all over the internet is not willing to receive correspondence regarding their research.