# Changing academic e-mail in a painless way

Tags: career-path, email

I'm leaving university soon and the academic email address I've been providing in my research papers and academic contacts to reach me will be deactivated by the end of November.

What action should I undertake not to lose them?

Comment: Not really an answer, but check whether your institution will forward email, either permanently or for some (long) period of time.

Comment: @BobBrown They told me, they won't forward anything as they will permanently delete it...

Comment: LinkedIn can be helpful here.  Also, it's amazing how little you will need to contact most people!

Comment: Are you a student or are you faculty?

Comment: Get an [ORCID](https://orcid.org/) ID if you plan on staying in academia, and use it in future academic publications. Then people can find you even if you switch institutions, change your name, or leave academia altogether - just update your contact details at orcid,org.

Comment: @JosephDoggie Have it :)

Comment: @ScottSeidman PhD student, finishing in November

Comment: @StephanKolassa Got ORCiD. It's indeed good idea... Though, maybe it would be also smart to have professional e-mail for academic stuff as I presume to change academia quite often! :)

Comment: It's becoming more common and accepted for academics to refer to a personal email account like a gmail for all correspondence, then this problem never arises.

Answer (score 17):

Based on Buffy's answer and the comments, I still think you should try to make forwarding a policy.

Assuming that isn't going work; *right now* download all of your email and extract the addresses of those with whom you've corresponded.  At least, you'll be able to contact them in the future.

Add a .sig to your email saying, "I'll be leaving this address soon.  My personal website, https://example.com, has contact information."

If you don't have a "permanent" email address, get one.  Gmail is free, and paid addresses are not expensive.  Begin referring people to that address *right now*.

Comment: I am going to do that immediately and turn on forwarding. I would eventually go for paid address - can you recommend me something?

Comment: @farmaceut I've been very satisfied with Fastmail, but check whether a suitable Gmail address might be available.  There's also Outlook.com and mac.com if you're part of the Appleverse.

Comment: Yeah, I could either create gmail or use iCloud one, although was considering something more professional and actually permanent so I wouldn't stick with each and every academic e-mail I might be provided with in the ~academic career~

Comment: @farmaceut  If you have your own domain for your web page, Fastmail (and others) will host your email using your own domain name.  That said, I don't see anything unprofessional about gmail; just don't be tequilakid@gmail.com.

Comment: @farmaceut A decent number of people in my field use gmail for work emails also, and it's becoming more common.  See also: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/55413/19607 (from 8 years ago, when it was even less common)

Comment: @BobBrown  I run my site on .github.io, but unfortunately it doesn't provide an email address. I will consider gmail or icloud.

Comment: My supervisor is an associate professor and has started using gmail for a lot of work emails, I think he even puts it as his contact address on most of his articles.

Answer (score 11):

What you are experiencing is a common issue, and I don't know why there's no standard solution. Every time you move up the academic ladder, a new email address and lots of people who need to find a way to contact you.

I know this does not help you now, but the preventive measure is to use a personal email address for all correspondence, e.g. a Gmail account. Every year this seems to be more common.

Since you already have your institution's email listed, the best thing to do is to make sure that your personal website is easy to find through Google, and that your new email address is listed there. I know, that's not easy for J. Smith, A. Kim, and P. Rodriguez, but might be a solution if your name is uncommon. Even if your name is common, make sure that the text of the website includes lots of keywords related to your research, to help those looking for you. If your new institution provides space for personal/research webpages, make sure to use it, as these are ranked high by Google, as opposed to some @wordpress site. Also make sure to keep an active profile in academic social media sites like Researchgate, and even on sites like LinkedIn. That way, people can find you quickly.

I hate anything smelling of social media, and don't want to be served ads while reading email. When you use commercial "free" services, you are at the mercy of the company changing their terms. So my own solution has been to pay for my own domain and email address. The cost is <$40/year and gives me a permanent email address that I control. I find it's worth it.

Last, it used to be the thing that people would send email messages with "I've changed my email, please update your address book." These were sent to their whole email address book. I can't speak about the effectiveness of this approach, but since social media took over, I've been receiving less of that type of message.

Comment: But if you email everybody in your address book this **please** use BCC instead of CC.

Answer (score 6):

Your university may be willing to extend the life of your address upon request. They might also be willing to forward any mail to that address to another that you specify. I suggest that you ask and if they agree, provide them with an address that you control, perhaps gmail (not an endorsement).

Otherwise it is pretty difficult. Over time you can do things to make yourself visible (personal web page, for example) and update your address individually with your contacts.

Ask co-authors to forward mails to your permanent address when inquiries about your joint papers are made. Update editors on any email changes so that enquiries to a journal might (just possibly) come to you.

If you are "corresponding author" on a paper, use an email address that will endure.

But I also encourage universities to help students, especially graduate students, to remain visible through old email addresses. My own (former) university has done this to (at least) some extent. If yours doesn't, then perhaps you can convince the faculty there to demand it.

At one time Dartmouth College promised to make all student email addresses endure forever. I thought at the time that this was a brilliant move for purposes of maintaining contact with alums if nothing else. I don't know if that policy is still in place.

Comment: As I replied to the colleague above - they are not willing to do so.  

I have a personal website but it is not visible in the research papers so readers won't be able to track the e-mail unless they are aware of the website.

Comment: @farmaceut  Ask again about forwarding, especially if you have a good rapport with someone in information systems.  Also ask your faculty senator; maybe you can get the policy changed as Buffy has suggested.  Forwarding of email is very cheap, and there's no good reason not to do it.

Comment: @BobBrown I know it's not problematic to set forwarding but *they won't*.

Comment: @farmaceut  I understand.  Complain to your faculty senator.  Explain why this is a problem for everyone on the faculty.  Even if it doesn't do you any good, it might help someone in the future.

Answer (score 4):

### Prevent this situation

This will not help you today, but it might help another person in the future:

1. Get your own domain name and hosting service.
2. Create an email address for your domain.
3. Create a web page for your domain that lists your contact information.
4. Always use your own email address to send emails instead of the one your employer provides.
5. Forward your institutional emails to your personal address.  They may refuse to forward after you leave, but in my experience they will forward emails while you work there.

This looks more professional/official than a Gmail account.

I have used this method for many years with several institutions.  I have never needed to update any accounts with third party websites or tell anyone my email address has changed.  I have never lost emails because the institution removed my account.

Refusing to use my institutional email address has never caused me any real problems.  I do occasionally get confused questions about it, including questions from people who do not understand where domain names come from.