# Is it appropriate if my current affiliation is different from the ending of my email address?

Tags: publications, graduate-school, etiquette, paper-submission

I have a permanent email aliasing from my previous institute. My current academic affiliation (let's pretend it is Horvord University) does NOT give me a permanent email address.

Now, I am going to submit a paper to a journal and I wonder if it is considered professionally appropriate if I list Horvord as my affiliation but list my previous email as the contact?

Comment: If you're getting the permanent email aliasing, is it because you're a graduate of that institute? That would be the easiest case to explain, and fully professional. (When I was applying for jobs, I did so from my @alumni.Horvord.edu address. Go Horvord Irascible Cows! ;) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using your previous email would be perfectly fine. The few readers who even notice will probably not think twice about it, whereas e.g. a gmail address can look a bit unprofessional, despite being more permanent in many ways. After all, people will move around during a career, and may choose to use an account from a previous institution for a variety of reasons.

However, there are [more options](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/2872/17254). Perhaps you don't need to specify an email address at all, or you can acquire one through a professional organization, or a domain of your own.

Comment: A gmail address is fine. So its a free email service, and? - Unless one has the luxury of a permanent position, academic email addresses  are very much disposable and temporary - so a private email address does look better in many ways. What matters more is the style of the email address. - At least that signifies the author may still be contacted in the future.

Comment: @DetlevCM I don't have a problem with it myself, and I think the attitude to it is getting more favorable, just due to it becoming more common. Still, you would have to make the choice of using a less official looking address, and potentially dealing with negative views like [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/170/17254). (Some institutions also have policies against third party email services, but it would be quite upsetting if that applies to OP's situation...)

Comment: ...uff... I don't know what to say regarding people like this... And the idea that the e-mail address conveys anything is also a bit meaningless... Heck, one can have a different e-mail address on the paper and in the publishing system. I have my and my superiors institutional e-mail address on a submitted paper draft - while the journal's system holds a persistent private address. An e-mail adress really means very little... Heck, on a previous paper a colleague was denoted the corresponding author... And ironically, my most robust contact method is a private e-mail address.

Comment: And while professors often stay at the same institution, even that isn't guaranteed. Sometimes they change institutions and old e-mail addresses go stale... (Though in that case, one often has a better chance of finding a current e-mail address...)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think it is true to some degree.  I received such an email before and it made me wonder what is going on.

Although it is not really prohibited and people understand that situations cannot be generalized, it gives a strange feeling to some people at least.

It is like indentation and font size in a paper submission.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote, but I upvoted it to at least make up the downvote. To @HighGPA, I have the same feeling as Kay does. I assume you already left your previous institute. Using their address would probably give people an idea that you're still associated with them. I cannot say it's wrong. But, it just creates an un-necessary misunderstanding.